# Reverse function

Tags: function, assembly, reverse-engineering

I have been trying to reverse a quite simple looking function.
the function is presented in assembly:
(Argument is loaded into AX)

```
AND AX, 0xFFFE (round down to even number)
MUL AX (Multiply AX by AX ; the result is represented as DX:AX)
XOR AX,DX
```

The function can be described as: H(X) = F(X & 0xFFFE); F(X) = ((X * X) mod 2^16) xor ((X * X) div 2^16)

Calculated all of the values from 1 to 2^16 and plotted on matlab in order to "see" some function.

[image]

Can anyone help me find an answer to this? (when given y what is the argument x).
It might be that for some values there is more than one answer, so narrowing it down is my goal.

Thanks,
Or.

Comment: As a simple solution, generate a lookup table?

Comment: How fast do you want it? Since the input is tiny you can easily brute force it.

Comment: I don't have enough memory for a lookup table, nor do I want to brute force it.

Comment: You don't have 128k? What ancient system is this :)

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "Reverse?" Are you asking for the source code that creates the assembly or a set function that will return the original value that maps to the result?

Comment: When there would be no `xor ax,dx`, you would need sqrt(dx:ax) to get original value. I can't recall (in 5min) any sqrt trick (except approximations), so even without the xor reversing it would be a bit like brute forcing it. The additional `xor ax,dx` twist will probably ruin whatever bit properties that square had. So it looks to me like either LUT or bruteforcing it. The resulting values are not sparse enough to create list instead of full LUT I suppose?

Comment: Since the `AND` operation is already destructive, I would say there is no way to reverse this operation, since just due to this part you already have at least 2 input values giving the same output, so information is lost. Or did I misunderstand your question...?

Comment: Assuming this function's output is also `ax` (and not both `ax` and `dx`), then if the operation were fully reversible, your chart would be a full square without holes because it would have to be a 1:1 relationship for each possible input and output values... (Also I think in your function equation above it should be `H(X)` instead of `X` everywhere in the second part.)

Answer (score 1):

It's a [hash function.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function)
You can't reverse a hash function, because the whole point of it is that it's a one way function.
The multiply is clearly reversible, it's the xor that's not. By combining the low and high part of the multiplication you lose information.

As you can see in the plot there are some white spaces, because there are 2^16 spaces in that plot that means there are also different input values that hash to the same value.
This is common in a hash function.

The only way to 'reverse' it is to build a lookup table that translates output values into possible input values. However you will find that for every output values that be 1 or more input values.

An even number x an even number is always a multiple of 4.
So the low 2 bits are always 0, ergo the low 2 bits of the result are bits 16+17 of the multiplication.
Bits 2..15 are a mix of bits 2..15 xor bits 18..31.
A quick simulation shows 24350 unique outputs ergo on average <del>1.34</del> 0.34 duplicates for every input value, not bad.
The maximum number of collisions is 6, but most numbers don't collide.

For all those numbers that don't collide you can uniquely lookup your input value in the lookup table (all this disregarding odd input values obviously).